# ActiveMQ doesn't show queue MBean

Tags: activemq-classic, jmx

I have setup an embedded broker in my app and activated JMX Mbean publishing on the local JMX registry using Spring namespaces. 
I see the broker and other Mbeans however when I unfold the queue node, I see a 'folder' node named after the name of my declared queue but not the queue MBean in itself. I can only see the queue MBean if I invoke the remove queue operation on the broker MBean and remove this specific queue.

Here's my config :

```
<bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean" init-method="init" depends-on="broker">
    <property name="uniqueResourceName" value="XAactiveMQ" />
    <property name="xaConnectionFactory" ref="jmsXaConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="poolSize" value="5"/>
</bean>


<!-- Spring JMS Template -->
<bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" depends-on="broker">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="1000"/>
</bean>

<!-- ActiveMQ destinations -->
<amq:queue id="DispatchDestination" physicalName="dispatchQueue" />
<amq:queue id="testQueue" physicalName="test" />

<jms:listener-container transaction-manager="JtaTransactionManager" connection-factory="amqConnectionFactory" container-type="default" concurrency="2-5" acknowledge="transacted">
    <jms:listener  destination="dispatchQueue" ref="dispatchMessageListener" />
    <jms:listener  destination="test" ref="testMessageListener" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

Any ideas on what's happening?

regards,